# Recursive association with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, factory-bot

I have a `category` model. I am using ancestry gem to make it like a tree structure so that we can have sub categories. I have a simple factory for `category` that looks like this

```
factory :category do
  sequence(:name) { |n| "Category #{n}"}
end
```

I have another model `business` which has a `main_category` and a `sub_category`. Here is my factory for the business

```
factory :business do
  sequence(:name) { |n| "businnes#{n}"}
  sequence(:email) { |n| "busixy#{n}@example.com"}
  sequence(:website) { |n| "www.example#{n}.com"}
  association(:main_sub_category)
  main_category          {Business.main_sub_category.parent}

end
```

What I am trying to do here is to assign `main_sub_category` of the `business` a new category which is a `sub_category` and to assign the parent of that `category` to `main_category` of the business.

To get this I created a new factory called sub_category
    factory :category do
      sequence(:name) { |n| "Category #{n}"}
      factory :subcategory do |sub|
        sub.parent factory :category
      end
    end

When I try the above code I get this error

```
Factory already registered: category (FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError)
```

I tried another way to do it

```
 factory :category do
      sequence(:name) { |n| "Category #{n}"}
      factory :subcategory do |sub|
        sub.parent {FactoryGirl.create(:category)}
      end
    end
```

This way it works but when I create a business object using the factory

```
@business = FactoryGirl.create :business
```

It gives me validation error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name has already been taken
```

I have a uniqueness validation on category names.

Any has had this kind of a recursive factory issue kind help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it resolved, for some mysterious reason I don't understand my test db had a already had a single entry for a category with name Category1 which was creating the issue, manually deleted that row using mysql console and everthing works now.

I still wonder why database wasn't clear, since I never write to test db directly its the testcase that do it.. :S